# Windows users with smartcards using Lync Android app

Tags: lync, smartcard

We have a Windows network where users are required to log in using a smartcard instead of a password.

Is there a way of allowing our users to use the Andoroid/iOS Lync app, even though they don't have a Windows password?

Answer (score 1):

I've now developed software that does this. It allows users to log in to a website, using their smartcard and create a username and password only for use with Lync.

It uses kerberos delegation to authorise the user.

Check it out at http://agatdev.com/